# Spring message tag. How to only attempt to display if the property exists

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a messages.properties file, from which I want to display some text on my jsp file.

**messages.properties:**

```
my.message.key=hello world
```

**inside jsp:**

```
<spring:message code="my.message.key"/>
```

This works fine. But what if I want to check that this exists at all, and only try to display it if it does. So that I can, for example, hide the section that contains this message if I simply remove it from the properties file.

```
<c:if test="someTest">
   Bla bla bla
   <spring:message code="my.message.key.maybe.not.there"/>
</c:if>
```

Thanks.

**Edit (because of a comment):**

To be clear "someTest" above is what I don't know. That is the question. What is the test (to check if that property exists in my properties file)?

**Further Edit:**

The cleanest way I can find is to create a bespoke messages tag that does not throw an exception when the message key cannot be found, and go from there. I would still like to hear if there is a quicker way. I feel there must be.

Comment: You omitted the most important part: what do you write to "someTest"? It should look like `test="${not empty variable}"`

Comment: That's my question. If I knew that, I would be answering my own question.

Comment: Spring will, by default, throw an exception if the message doesn't exist. Message bundles aren't property files and shouldn't be used as such. They are used for I18N. What do you want to achieve with hidding the part if the message isn't present?

Comment: There are multiple use cases, it's a cheap way of feature toggling for example. The properties are reloadable and maintained in a content management system, they can be changed or removed dynamically without needing to bounce my web server. Aside: This is not true of my JSPs; this is an enterprise application, wherein I have limited tech freedom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need small change in above answer to work perfectly. Add default value as empty "" to spring theme, then if condition will return false if key doesn't found.

```
<spring:theme code="my.message.key" var="message" text=""/>
<c:if test="${not empty message}">
   here goes your code
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the mentioned unintended use, try this:

```
<spring:message code="my.message.key" var="message" />
<c:if test="${not empty message}">
   here goes your code
</c:if>
```

This requires the message to exist, but you can leave it blank.

Comment: It's not a bad compromise. I will up vote it but wont accept it as the answer as it does not satisfy all my criteria. I think the bespoke tag, although slight more upfront work, is better.